# conceiving a bus can adapter using stm32

Tags: qt, usb, can-bus

So here is the thing, I want to conceive a universal BUS CAN adapter using stm32 with a desktop interface using Qt.
Still in the conception phase, I'm wondering how to treat the frames coming from the stm to PC GUI, weather 1) as a USB frame; in this case, how to encapsulate and decapsulate them into CAN frames and is there a Qt library to facilitate the job, or 2) as a CAN frame in this case I found the QCanBusDevice and QCanBusFrame Class which seem to be so helpful but in this case a CAN plugin  must be specified during the object creation. So what should i do?

Comment: Did you go through Media Agnostic USB specification and see if that helps?

Comment: Just checked and I do not see its possible using MA-USB. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't really matter what you do because you're designing a custom protocol that rides on top of USB. Here you have an option of implementing a USB communications class device so that you don't need custom drivers nor libusb - especially given that the performance of libusb on Unixes is abysmal.

Once the data is available to the userspace, you can access it using `QSerialPort`. You'll have to frame the CAN frames somehow, as serial port is a stream-oriented transport and doesn't know of any packets. Most trivially, you can encapsulate the frames using [RFC 1662 HDLC octet-stuffed framing](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1662#page-8). You can encapsulate the commands to your device, and their responses, in the same fashion, using one of the fields, e.g. the ADDRESS field, to multiplex CAN data and commands/responses.

If you now wish to expose this device to the Qt Serial Bus framework, you'll have to [write a custom CAN plugin](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcanbus-backends.html#implementing-a-custom-can-plugin) to access it.

To give some idea of how much code this is: total for Qt code and microcontroller code should be well under 1500 lines for a proof-of-concept. A minimal demo would be probably <400 lines of Qt code and <400 lines of STM32 code.

Comment: so if I got it right, the frame will be sent from the GUI as a CAN frame, the encapsulation/decapsulation thing will be treated by the STM since the serial port is a stream-oriented transport and doesn't differentiate between packets.
if so, i have another question, how will the STM will differentiate between configuration messages (to configure the CAN baud rates for example) and data messages? I guess I need to add a heading isn't  ?

Comment: If you look at the HDLC protocol I linked to, you'll see that there are several fields you can appropriate for your own use. You can e.g. use the ADDRESS field values for multiplexing. E.g. 0xFF is a CAN frame, 0x00 is command #0, 0x01 is command #1, etc. Same goes for replies: when STM receives a CAN fame, it sends it out to address 0xFF, when it replies to command #0 it sends to address 0x00, and so on. HDLC originally was used for X.25 (an open and well documented protocol, BTW). The way it's used for PPP is a very narrow subset of X.25. You can drop the fields you don't care about.